# Ngnx Redirect Working when we access the URL manually, but not working when we access the URL through website navigation

Tags: nginx

I need help in resolving this issue.

I have written a similar redirect rule as below in Nginx host file.

**rewrite ^/abcd/(.*) https://$server_name/xyz/$1 permanent;**

The redirect is working if we access the url manually by hitting in the browser, but if we navigate through the website the redirect is not working. But, again if we refresh the page it is working. Can some one help in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which app you using? which technology? does your navigation calls Ajax based?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the quick response and question. Because of which I found what was the issue and why it is not working. Actually we are using single page applications and not validating the 301 redirects in Megamenu due to performance issue, that is why it is not working until unless we force refresh the page.